# Concat tensor of[None, 192] with tensor of [1,128]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensor

How to concatenate tensors of shapes [None, 128] with tensor of [1,128]. Here the first tensor will some data of unknown length and the second tensor is fixed tensor not dependant on data size. The final output should be of shape[None, 328]. This is a part of a neural network concatenation.

I tried

```
> c = Concatenate(axis = -1, name = 'DQN_Input')([ a, b])
```

Here a.shape = (None, 192) and b.shape = (1,128)
But this does not work.
The error is

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching
> shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 192),
> (1, 128)]

Comment: What error message do you get? Please add it to your question

Comment: Added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `tf.repeat` on `b` based on the first dimension of `a` to generate the same shape tensor. Here is a simple working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.keras.layers.Input((192, ), name = 'a')
alpha = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,),name = 'Alpha')
b = tf.matmul(alpha, a, transpose_a=True)
b = tf.repeat(b, repeats=tf.shape(a)[0], axis=0)
c = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = -1, name = 'DQN_Input')([ a, b])
model = tf.keras.Model([a, alpha], c)
tf.print(model((tf.random.normal((5, 192)), tf.random.normal((5, 1)))).shape)
```

```
TensorShape([5, 384])
```

Comment: that doesnt work. The shape remains same.
I also tried 
tf.reshape(b, (a.get_shape()[0], b.get_shape()[1])) since it is a tensorflow layer. I get error
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, 128). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Comment: Can you post where exactly you are trying to concatenate ? I understand that `a` is part of your network but where does `b` come from?

Comment: Actually b is like a weighted combination of the batch. (for example average of input a)
b = Dot(axes = 1, name = 'Fleet_Context')([alpha_K, a])
Here alpha_K.shape = (None,1), that is it is a vector of size equal to the batch size

Comment: The matrix multiplication is fine but the underlying issue is the same as the shape of b is the same (1,128). The concatenation doesnt work

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to your question, including how you create alpha_K?

Comment: alpha is nothing but an input tensor.
alpha = Input(1,name = 'Alpha')

Comment: But how do you plan to take the dot product from `alpha` and `a` when alpha has the shape (None,1) and `a` the `(None, 192)`? The dimensions have to be equal and this is causing your problem

Comment: Here I tranpose alpha so that the new dimension is (1, None) and then tf.matmul works the same like dot product as you had pointed earlier.
tf.matmul(alpha, a, transpose_a=True)

Comment: You are getting the matmul wrong here

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: seems to work....thankyou